# Django 2 Redirect to next page on form submit

Tags: django, pagination

I have a Django 2 app paginating through one large 'place' record at a time, and the template adds some radio button sets to each, which the user can check in the course of validating what's in the record. I wrap each record in a form, and upon submit I want to a) create a new record from those selections in a separate 'review' model/table, and b) redirect to the paginator's next page.

I have no trouble creating the new record from the form radio inputs, then redirecting to a confirmation page. The problem is how to redirect to the same view/template but advancing the page.

I tried redirecting to the same view but a different url:

```
path('place/', views.place, name='place'),
path('place/next', views.place, name='placenext'),
```

then parsing the request object in the view, but this fails without error:

```
def place(request):

  paginator = Paginator(place_list, 1)
  req = request.path
  page = request.GET.get('page')  

  if req[-4:] == 'next':
    records = paginator.get_page(str(int(page)+1))
  else:
    records = paginator.get_page(page)

  context = {
    'records': records, 'page': page
  }

  return render(request, 'review/place.html', context=context)
```

I also tried many other things, including inserting `?page=` in a few ways, but it's fumbling in the dark because there is no indication in docs of how to accomplish this. As far as I can tell there is nothing in the request object that will let me make the view 'dual-purpose' - simply rendering a record or advancing the page.

**[ correct answer, due to @Satendra below ]**

Single path, single view with return the same whether GET or POST, but if POST, create new record with form contents. Thx

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    # create Related record
    relform = request.POST
    related = Related.objects.create(
        placeid = relform['placeid'],
        ...,
        ...
    )
pprint(locals())
return render(request, 'review/place.html', context=context)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't create multiple endpoints for the same view.

> Just add the request method check, and when the method is **POST** use
>   `redirect` method to redirect it to the same view

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render

def place(request):
  if request.method == 'GET':
     ...
     # your code lies here when request is GET
     return render(request, 'review/place.html', context=context)
  else:
     return redirect('place')
```